# ReferenceError: React not defined in tests

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jestjs

I'm using the laravel mix and it appears that I cannot get jest to find react if I am interpreting this issue properly.

My Test:

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import AppLayout from "../AppLayout";

test("it renders", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <AppLayout pageTitle={undefined}>App</AppLayout>
    );
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2",
        "jest": "^24.5.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.15",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.14",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.17.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
        "js-file-download": "^0.4.5",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "npm-check-updates": "^3.1.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "react-select": "^2.4.2"
    },
    "jest": {


"roots": [
        "resources/js/app"
    ],
    "transform": {".*": "./node_modules/babel-jest"}
}
```

}

.babelrc

```
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
        },
        "development": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined

      18 |         const { expanded } = this.state;
      19 |
    > 20 |         return (
         |         ^
      21 |             <div>
      22 |                 <nav
      23 |                     className="navbar"
```

I've tried everything I could find on stackoverflow & google to solve this issue. Including removing my node_modules folder and rebuilding many times to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so, the answer to this question is really interesting.
So as you may know if you just `import { Component } from 'react';`
Then `export default class MyComponent extends Component` it WILL work and render in the browser. However when you go to test with jest you will get React undefined even if you import it into your test file.

The solution is simple, change it to `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Comment: I have the same issue, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: @ataravati are you sure you imported in test file??

Comment: @metalheadcoder This was more than a year ago. I don't remember.

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this way: `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it couldn't possibly work, but it fixes it. 

Answer (score 0):

import React in test

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

At the VERY top of my test file, I put:

/**

- @jest-environment jsdom
  */

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Issue definitely looks to be with your babel config, the react preset targets browsers using es6 which jest which targets node does not, try this

```
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "presets": [ ["env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]]
        },
        "development": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
        }
    }
}
```

Also add this to your `webpack.mix.js` to make jest aware of node_modules(assumes your component is located in the a /modules directory)

```
.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js/modules'), 'node_modules']
  }
})
```

You can read more on how to configure babel [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files/#env-option).

Comment: I see dependencies, not sure how that relates to babel being configured properly.

Comment: I have the babel presets specified in my package.json. under "babel": {} ..

Comment: That's great and while that works fine for mix, which uses webpack to interpret es6 imports babel-jest won't because it uses nodejs to run tests. So that means your tests will need to use a different target than your actual application. I don't see your .babelrc so I don't know which environments you are targeting for testing but I assume you are trying to target browsers for everything.

Comment: results are the same across the board no matter where i'm specifying my configuration for babel.

Comment: .babelrc config?

Comment: Using a .babelrc file has no affect over using a babel.config.js file. If you're asking to see it, it's literally the equivalent of what I had in my package.json

Comment: Well since it's most likely a babel config issue, your reluctance to provide the .babelrc only hurts your own chances of getting the question answered. Tag me if you decide to provide it and I'll try to help out. Here's a good article to explain in more detail https://medium.com/@adiach3nko/how-to-configure-jest-testing-framework-for-laravel-mix-775a03b1c71

Comment: That's the literal tutorial i followed and it netted the same results.

Comment: Added my .babelrc

Answer (score -1):

Update the packages using this:

`npm audit fix`

or:

`npm audit fix --force`

It worked for me but it may break some of the old packages you use?! I don't know. Please complete this answer if you know that.